# Create new column based with boolean

Tags: r

Using the iris dataset. Say I want to create a new column called "nice flower" with the following conditions:

```
[(Sepal.Length > 5.0) && (Petal.Length < 1.5)]
```

How would I do this?

Comment: `iris$nice_flower<-(iris$Petal.Length<1.5) & (iris$Sepal.Length>5)`

Answer (score 1):

In `base` R:

```
iris$nice_flower<-(iris$Petal.Length<1.5) & (iris$Sepal.Length>5)
iris[iris$nice_flower==T,] #for verification
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is using `ifelse`

```
iris$nice_flower <- ifelse(iris$Sepal.Length > 5.0 & iris$Petal.Length < 1.5, 1, 0)
```

Another options is using `as.integer` (I think akrun had mentioned this) which is better than using `ifelse`

```
as.integer(iris$Sepal.Length > 5.0 & iris$Petal.Length < 1.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use within function to create a new column

```
iris <- within(iris , nice_flower <-ifelse(iris$Sepal.Length > 5.0 & iris$Petal.Length < 1.5, T, F))
iris <- subset(iris, nice_flower %in% T)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   > iris$nice_flower <- iris$Sepal.Length > 5.0 & iris$Petal.Length < 1.5
   > result <- iris[iris$nice_flower == T,]
   > result
   #    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species nice_flower
   # 1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa        TRUE
   # 15          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2  setosa        TRUE
   # 17          5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4  setosa        TRUE
   # 18          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.3  setosa        TRUE
   # 29          5.2         3.4          1.4         0.2  setosa        TRUE
   # 34          5.5         4.2          1.4         0.2  setosa        TRUE
   # 37          5.5         3.5          1.3         0.2  setosa        TRUE
```

Comment: Indeed, it is just my answer a little bit reformatted and posted more than 45mins later ... :(